# Python Pandas: Dropped Rows Based on Recurrence Value From Previous Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm at my wits end here. Any help would be very much appreciated!

This is my current data. The product changed from A.1 to A.2. What I want is when the A.1 turns into A.2, I want the rest of my data to only start counting cycle time for A.2. The same for B.1 and B.3.

Here is the current data.

```
+---------+-----------+--+
| Product | CycleTime |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.1     | 10        |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.1     | 5         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.1     | 1         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.1     | 2         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.1     | 1         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.2     | 5         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.2     | 1         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.1     | 2         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.1     | 10        |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.2     | 10        |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| B.1     | 1         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| B.1     | 2         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| B.1     | 1         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| B.3     | 5         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| B.1     | 1         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| B.3     | 2         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| B.1     | 10        |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
```

Here is what i'm trying to produce.

```
+---------+-----------+--+
| Product | CycleTime |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.1     | 10        |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.1     | 5         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.1     | 1         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.1     | 2         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.1     | 1         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.2     | 5         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.2     | 1         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| A.2     | 10        |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| B.1     | 1         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| B.1     | 2         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| B.1     | 1         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| B.3     | 5         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
| B.3     | 2         |  |
+---------+-----------+--+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop duplicates and keep the first values, the index of the next product show you from where it is no longer possible to find the current product:

```
find_pos = lambda x: x.drop_duplicates('Product')['Product'].shift().dropna() \
          .rename_axis('not_valid_after').reset_index()

conds = df.groupby(df['Product'].str.split('.').str[0]) \
          .apply(find_pos).reset_index(drop=True)

print(conds)

# Output:
   not_valid_after Product
0                5     A.1  # 5 is the first index of A.2
1               13     B.1  # 13 is the first index of B.3
```

Now you can filter your dataframe:

```
out = df.drop(conds.apply(lambda x: df.loc[df['Product'] == x['Product']]
                                      .loc[x['not_valid_after']:].index.tolist(),
                           axis=1).explode().dropna().tolist())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Product  CycleTime
0      A.1         10
1      A.1          5
2      A.1          1
3      A.1          2
4      A.1          1
5      A.2          5
6      A.2          1
9      A.2         10
10     B.1          1
11     B.1          2
12     B.1          1
13     B.3          5
15     B.3          2
```

Answer (score 0):

setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ProductType":["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
        "Product":["A.1", "A.1", "A.1", "A.1", "A.1", "A.2", "A.2", "A.1", "A.1", "A.2", "B.1", "B.1", "B.1", "B.3", "B.1", "B.3", "B.1"],
        "CycleTime":[10,5,1,2,1,5,1,2,10,10,1,2,1,5,1,2,10],
    }
)
```

Create an order between products.  The order between different product types does not matter, only within each product type.  I.e. take several partial orderings and stitch them together to create a total ordering.  You may have to do this manually, perhaps you can do it programmatically, it depends on your problem.

```
order = ["A.1", "A.2", "B.1", "B.2", "B.3"]
```

Create a map, and its inverse which associate each product with its position in the order.

```
mapping = dict(enumerate(order))
inversemapping= {v:k for k,v in mapping.items()}
```

The idea is, for each product type, to map the product to its order value, and calculate the cumulative maximum of these order values, before mapping back to the products.

```
df.groupby("ProductType").apply(lambda d: d["Product"].map(inversemapping).cummax().map(mapping)).values
```

You will get the following numpy array:

```
 array(['A.1', 'A.1', 'A.1', 'A.1', 'A.1', 'A.2', 'A.2', 'A.2', 'A.2',
   'A.2', 'B.1', 'B.1', 'B.1', 'B.3', 'B.3', 'B.3', 'B.3'],
  dtype=object)
```